# How do i test if response cache working for an API in WSO2 3.0.0 APIM?

Tags: wso2, ibm-api-management, apim

Steps I tried!

1. Run ALLInONE wso2 3.0.0
   -published an API- pizza shack
2. Run load test on it for 5 min with 20 concurrent users. Stopped it
3. Went to publisher enabled response cache
4. restart server
5. Run load test for 5 min with 20 concurrent users

But to my surprise, all results were the same

Same thing I tried in our production environment But there also facing the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

Since the backend of the Sample API is deployed on the same server, you may not see a much difference. Try with an external (maybe slow) backend service.

Comment: in our production environment also I have tried but same issue there "no improvement due to caching"